# How to use A4 instead of letterpaper?

Tags: paper-size

I am working with a template which uses letterpage. Yet I need it to be A4.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0em}
```

How do I change it?

Comment: `a4paper` is the option.

Comment: Is `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}` what you're after?

Comment: @CountZero Indeed it was. Silly me was trying only with `A4`.

Comment: @CountZero Do you mind adding it as an answer?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The `article` class has an option for A4 (210 mm x 297 mm) paper:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
```

other possible options for page size are:

- `a5paper` - A5: 148 mm x 210 mm, that is half of A4, basically
- `b5paper` - B5: 250 mm x 176 mm
- `letterpaper` - Letter: 215.9 mm x 279.4 mm
- `legalpaper` - Legal: 215.9 mm x 355.6 mm

Comment: You also need to fix the call to `geometry` in the MWE.

Comment: In addition to `\documentclass[...paper]{...}`, `\usepackage{geometry}` is also needed. Without the latter, `latex` won't insert the `\special{papersize=...}`.

Answer (score 8):

You should also have a look to KOMA script, instead of the default article class:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
```

Comment: What are the benefits over the default article class?

Comment: there are a lot of improvements. As you are from Germany, please have a look at http://www.komascript.de/ or http://www.amazon.de/KOMA-Script-Anleitung-Sammlung-Klassen-Paketen/dp/3865414591/