# How to set paper size in LaTeX outside of documentclass

Tags: document-classes, documentclass-writing, paper-size

I am looking at [How to use A4 instead of letterpaper?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110039/how-to-use-a4-instead-of-letterpaper/110048) and wondering how I can create a custom documentclass like `\documentclass{foo}`, and then have another function like `\foosetsize{a4paper}` right after that somehow, rather than putting the paper dimensions inside `documentclass` options. How can I do that?

So instead of:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{foo}
```

It would be something like:

```
\documentclass{foo}
\setpapersize{a4paper}
```

Comment: Have you looked into the geometry package?  It's the usual method for adjusting paper sizing.

Comment: `\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm, paperheight=10cm]{geometry}`

Comment: Note that if you change the paper size without changing the margins etc. everything will wind up in the upper left corner.  The right and bottom margins are whatever is left over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Help yourself to an introduction into LaTeX, that'll make your work easier.

To load options there are three ways:

1. Global option, `\documentclass[global-option1, global-option2]{article}`
2. Load them with the package: `\usepackage[options]{packagename}`
3. With a command provided by the package.

You are looking for the third, something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
```

You get the manual of geometry and most other packages by typing `texdoc packagename` on the command line. If you work under Windows, that's cmd.exe.